# RD App windows locking up when connecting/disconnecting docking station

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016, rdweb

We have a selection of 8 assorted Dell laptops - Latitude 5490 and 3390, XPS 13 2-in-1 - all less than 12 months old.

We also have a couple of different docking stations in use, Dell D6000's and one Dell WD15 also less than a year old, connected to extra 23" monitors to be used as a "wide" desktop when connected to the laptops.

We publish some applications through RDWeb from a Windows RDS server - both of these servers are Windows 2016.

What happens is the application runs happily, but if we plug a laptop into a docking station while the app is running (or unplug from the docking station) the application locks up and doesn't respond to key presses.  We can close it from the user's laptop taskbar or by clicking the "X" but other key presses are ignored.  We can also move the Windows by dragging the title bars.

Reversing the attach/detach of the docking station does not resolve the problem.

The problem affects any application that we launch through RDWeb, including "standard" Windows apps like File Explorer.

Any  ideas how we can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How are the laptops connected to the network when docked and undocked? It sounds like the laptops are losing their network connection... thereby losing their connection to the RemoteApps.

Comment: Hi Joe - the laptops are connected wirelessly throughout, the docking stations are not hardwired.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I have seen DELL-Machines changing their MAC when connected through a dock. Can you check that?

Comment: Hi bjoster - the MAC address doesn't change, nor does the IP address;  the only connection being used is the wireless connection (Intel dual band wireless-AC 8265) built into the laptop, because the docking stations don't have network connections.